# How to manage camera for move to game character smoothly?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am making game for android using libgdx my requirement is that when character play game normaly then  we work as

```
         if velocity == normal(==25) 
        cam.position.y = character.position.y;
```

But in case getting some power then need is that we smoothly  increese y-position of character
for that I assign as

```
             if when velocity >25(means get power)
           cam.position.y = character.position.y-screenHieght/3;
```

it is working but character is not move smoothly move with jerk and no real effect is comming.
        Please anyone help me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, are you saying that your camera is moving drastically when a power up is used instead of having a smooth movement to its destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After giving a second read to your question I think you are asking how to smoothly update your camera regardless of the speed the player is moving at.

Here's how i update my camera :

```
     protected void updateCamera() {
        float tX = cameraObjective.pos.x - cam.position.x;
        float tY = cameraObjective.pos.y - cam.position.y;
        float newX = cam.position.x + tX;
        float newY = cam.position.y + tY;
        if ( newX < camBounds.x || newX > camBounds.x + camBounds.width ){
            tX = 0;
        }
        if ( newY < camBounds.y  - camBounds.height || newY > camBounds.y  ){
            tY = 0;
        }
        cam.translate(tX, tY, 0);
    }
```

cambounds is a huge rectangle which defines the camera's movement limits, so you might omit that part if it's not helpful for your case